# How to pause Main thread to execute 2 methods concurrently, then return back to Main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a class which contains 5 methods. At a certain point in the program, I would like to run 2 of the methods concurrently.  The below diagram illustrates what I’m talking about.
After method2() completes, I want method3() and method4() to run at the same time. Method3() and method4() are essentially doing the exact same thing but have isolated resources and therefore should not have to be synchronized.
When method3() and method4() complete, I would like the Aux threads destroyed and the program to return back to the Main thread.  What is the best way to do this?

[image: Image of program threads]

I tried calling ExecutorService, but this appears to create threads which run concurrently with the Main thread - not pause the Main thread.

```
 ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

            // method reference introduced in Java 8
            executorService.submit(this::method3());
            executorService.submit(this::method4());

            // close executorService
            executorService.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`executorService.submit` returns `Future<T>`, on which you can call `get()` to block your thread. So:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

Future<?> f1 = executorService.submit(this::method3());
Future<?> f2 = executorService.submit(this::method4());

f1.get();
f2.get();

executorService.shutdown();
```

`f1.get()` and `f2.get()` would block main thread until both futures are done. Also, if you need to create executor service multiple times, it'd be better to keep executor service without calling `shutdown()` on it. Threads will simply park.

Comment: Of course, it would work just as well, and it would use fewer resources, if the program would submit only _one_ task to the thread pool, and let the main thread perform the other task.